# Show Multisite Subpages WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I have a Multisite installation:
1: The main site - domain.com 
2: other sites - domain.com/some-url

**FIXED:** So far so good. My script shows the content automatically below the header and not where my shortcode is inserted.

```
function subsites_list_sites() {
    $subsites = get_sites();    
    if ( ! empty ( $subsites ) ) {  
        echo '<div class="subsites-container">';
        foreach( $subsites as $subsite ) {
            $subsite_id = get_object_vars( $subsite )["blog_id"];
            $subsite_name = get_blog_details( $subsite_id )->blogname;
            $subsite_link = get_blog_details( $subsite_id )->siteurl;
            echo '<div class="subtite-item site-' . $subsite_id . '">
            <a class="thumb" href="' . $subsite_link . '">Here i want the featured image/thumbnail to display</a>
            <a class="title-link" href="' . $subsite_link . '"><h3 class="title">' . $subsite_name . '</h3></a>
            <a class="excerpt" href="' . $subsite_link . '"><p>Here i want excerpt<p></a>
            <a class="btn-link" href="' . $subsite_link . '">GO TO WEBSITE</a>
            </div>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
add_shortcode( 'subsites_list_sites_sc', 'subsites_list_sites' );
```

Comment: You should open another question for the "MISSING" part. It's actually a totally different issue and is not related with shortcodes

Comment: I will do that.. Thanks for taking care of the new guy here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortcodes should return the html not print it in the shortcode function.

Try like this:

```
function subsites_list_sites() {
    $subsites = get_sites();
    $returnHtml = '';    
    if ( ! empty ( $subsites ) ) {  
        $returnHtml .= '<div class="subsites-container">';
        foreach( $subsites as $subsite ) {
            $subsite_id = get_object_vars( $subsite )["blog_id"];
            $subsite_name = get_blog_details( $subsite_id )->blogname;
            $subsite_link = get_blog_details( $subsite_id )->siteurl;
            $returnHtml .= '<div class="subtite-item site-' . $subsite_id . '">
            <a class="thumb" href="' . $subsite_link . '">Here i want the featured image/thumbnail to display</a>
            <a class="title-link" href="' . $subsite_link . '"><h3 class="title">' . $subsite_name . '</h3></a>
            <a class="excerpt" href="' . $subsite_link . '"><p>Here i want excerpt<p></a>
            <a class="btn-link" href="' . $subsite_link . '">GO TO WEBSITE</a>
            </div>';
        }
        $returnHtml .= '</div>';
    }
    return $returnHtml;
}
```

> **Output**
>   The return value of a shortcode handler function is inserted
>   into the post content output in place of the shortcode macro. Remember
>   to use return and not echo - anything that is echoed will be output to
>   the browser, but it won't appear in the correct place on the page.
>   https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Output

Comment: Just did.. Will you +1 my question :)